# How to fix "Data must be 1-dimensional" error

Tags: numpy

I have resolved all errors up till now. I am not quite sure I understand the problem except for I get the error "Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional". I post the complete code and the error Is occurring in the last two lines, I tried to solve in different method but coul'd find any solution.. I appreciate your help

Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import datetime
import pyfolio as pf
def mpPDF(var,q,pts):
# Marcenko-Pastur pdf
# q=T/N
    eMin,eMax=var*(1-(1./q)**.5)**2,var*(1+(1./q)**.5)**2
    eVal=np.linspace(eMin,eMax,pts)
    pdf=q/(2*np.pi*var*eVal)*((eMax-eVal)*(eVal-eMin))**.5
    pdf=pd.Series(pdf,index=eVal)
    return pdf
from sklearn.neighbors.kde import KernelDensity
def getPCA(matrix):
# Get eVal,eVec from a Hermitian matrix
    eVal,eVec=np.linalg.eigh(matrix)
    indices=eVal.argsort()[::-1] # arguments for sorting eVal desc
    eVal,eVec=eVal[indices],eVec[:,indices]
    eVal=np.diagflat(eVal)
    return eVal,eVec
#---------------------------------------------------
def fitKDE(obs,bWidth=.25,kernel='gaussian',x=None):
# Fit kernel to a series of obs, and derive the prob of obs
# x is the array of values on which the fit KDE will be evaluated
    if len(obs.shape)==1:obs=obs.reshape(-1,1)
    kde=KernelDensity(kernel=kernel,bandwidth=bWidth).fit(obs)
    if x is None:x=np.unique(obs).reshape(-1,1)
    if len(x.shape)==1:x=x.reshape(-1,1)
    logProb=kde.score_samples(x) # log(density)
    pdf=pd.Series(np.exp(logProb),index=x.flatten())
    return pdf
x=np.random.normal(size=(10000,1000))
eVal0,eVec0=getPCA(np.corrcoef(x,rowvar=0))
pdf0=mpPDF(1.,q=x.shape[0]/float(x.shape[1]),pts=1000)
pdf1=fitKDE(np.diag(eVal0),bWidth=.01) # empirical pdf
plt.plot(pdf0)
plt.plot(pdf1)
#Add Signal to a Random Covariance Matrix
def getRndCov(nCols,nFacts):
    w=np.random.normal(size=(nCols,nFacts))
    cov=np.dot(w,w.T) # random cov matrix, however not full rank
    cov+=np.diag(np.random.uniform(size=nCols)) # full rank cov
    return cov
#---------------------------------------------------
def cov2corr(cov):
# Derive the correlation matrix from a covariance matrix
    std=np.sqrt(np.diag(cov))
    corr=cov/np.outer(std,std)
    corr[corr<-1],corr[corr>1]=-1,1 # numerical error
    return corr
#---------------------------------------------------
alpha,nCols,nFact,q=.995,1000,100,10
cov=np.cov(np.random.normal(size=(nCols*q,nCols)),rowvar=0)
cov=alpha*cov+(1-alpha)*getRndCov(nCols,nFact) # noise+signal
corr0=cov2corr(cov)
eVal0,eVec0=getPCA(corr0)

#2.4 FITTING THE MARCENKO–PASTUR PDF
from scipy.optimize import minimize

#---------------------------------------------------
def findMaxEval(eVal,q,bWidth):
    # Find max random eVal by fitting Marcenko’s dist
    out=minimize(lambda *x:errPDFs(*x),.5,args=(eVal,q,bWidth),
    bounds=((1E-5,1-1E-5),))
    if out['success']:var=out['x'][0]
    else:var=1
    eMax=var*(1+(1./q)**.5)**2
    return eMax,var

#---------------------------------------------------
eMax0,var0=findMaxEval(np.diag(eVal0),q,bWidth=.01)
nFacts0=eVal0.shape[0]-np.diag(eVal0)[::-1].searchsorted(eMax0)
```

The Error occurs when I write

```
eMax0,var0=findMaxEval(np.diag(eVal0),q,bWidth=.01)
```

The error is the following 
Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional

Comment: Hi, It would be helpful if you could provide the full log of the error so as it will be easy to trace the origin.

Comment: Print the shapes of *all* the inputs. You should not be relying on SO for basic debugging and documentation

Comment: What's the shape of `eval0`?  What does `np.diag(eVal0)` do?  If it works, what shape?  What odes `findMaxEval` expect?

Comment: I added the full error, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your responses, the code is from a book and I'm tried to replicate.. all the code seems to work well until I get to this part

```
eMax0,var0=findMaxEval(np.diag(eVal0),q,bWidth=.01)
```

the full error log is the following

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-3d83ecc82cac> in <module>
      1 #---------------------------------------------------
----> 2 eMax0,var0=findMaxEval(np.diag(eVal0),q,bWidth=.01)
      3 nFacts0=eVal0.shape[0]-np.diag(eVal0)[::-1].searchsorted(eMax0)

<ipython-input-26-45fdc0305285> in findMaxEval(eVal, q, bWidth)
      3     # Find max random eVal by fitting Marcenko’s dist
      4     out=minimize(lambda *x:errPDFs(*x),.5,args=(eVal,q,bWidth),
----> 5     bounds=((1E-5,1-1E-5),))
      6     if out['success']:var=out['x'][0]
      7     else:var=1

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py in minimize(fun, x0, args, method, jac, hess, hessp, bounds, constraints, tol, callback, options)
    598     elif meth == 'l-bfgs-b':
    599         return _minimize_lbfgsb(fun, x0, args, jac, bounds,
--> 600                                 callback=callback, **options)
    601     elif meth == 'tnc':
    602         return _minimize_tnc(fun, x0, args, jac, bounds, callback=callback,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\lbfgsb.py in _minimize_lbfgsb(fun, x0, args, jac, bounds, disp, maxcor, ftol, gtol, eps, maxfun, maxiter, iprint, callback, maxls, **unknown_options)
    333             # until the completion of the current minimization iteration.
    334             # Overwrite f and g:
--> 335             f, g = func_and_grad(x)
    336         elif task_str.startswith(b'NEW_X'):
    337             # new iteration

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\lbfgsb.py in func_and_grad(x)
    278     if jac is None:
    279         def func_and_grad(x):
--> 280             f = fun(x, *args)
    281             g = _approx_fprime_helper(x, fun, epsilon, args=args, f0=f)
    282             return f, g

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py in function_wrapper(*wrapper_args)
    324     def function_wrapper(*wrapper_args):
    325         ncalls[0] += 1
--> 326         return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
    327 
    328     return ncalls, function_wrapper

<ipython-input-26-45fdc0305285> in <lambda>(*x)
      2 def findMaxEval(eVal,q,bWidth):
      3     # Find max random eVal by fitting Marcenko’s dist
----> 4     out=minimize(lambda *x:errPDFs(*x),.5,args=(eVal,q,bWidth),
      5     bounds=((1E-5,1-1E-5),))
      6     if out['success']:var=out['x'][0]

<ipython-input-25-64131afdcf75> in errPDFs(var, eVal, q, bWidth, pts)
      2 def errPDFs(var,eVal,q,bWidth,pts=1000):
      3     # Fit error
----> 4     pdf0=mpPDF(var,q,pts) # theoretical pdf
      5     pdf1=fitKDE(eVal,bWidth,x=pdf0.index.values) # empirical pdf
      6     sse=np.sum((pdf1-pdf0)**2)

<ipython-input-2-85275240fe2a> in mpPDF(var, q, pts)
      5     eVal=np.linspace(eMin,eMax,pts)
      6     pdf=q/(2*np.pi*var*eVal)*((eMax-eVal)*(eVal-eMin))**.5
----> 7     pdf=pd.Series(pdf,index=eVal)
      8     return pdf

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __init__(self, data, index, dtype, name, copy, fastpath)
    312                     data = data.copy()
    313             else:
--> 314                 data = sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy, raise_cast_failure=True)
    315 
    316                 data = SingleBlockManager(data, index, fastpath=True)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy, raise_cast_failure)
    727     elif subarr.ndim > 1:
    728         if isinstance(data, np.ndarray):
--> 729             raise Exception("Data must be 1-dimensional")
    730         else:
    731             subarr = com.asarray_tuplesafe(data, dtype=dtype)

Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

Thank you